# C# TCP socket implementation not working, similar implemention in PHP does

Tags: c#, php, sockets, tcp

I have implemented a TCP client in c# and in PHP.

Both connect to a TCP server / port and read the welcome message of the server. This works and both implementations put out the response. After that both clients send data to the server.

The C# implemention throws the exception "System.IO.IOException: Read failure"

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Operation timed out." at reading
>   the next response of the server.

The PHP implementation is working.

The C# implementation stopped working a few hours ago, I have no clue why. On different network the C# implementation works as well.

Is there any core difference in the implemention of TCP sockets in C# / PHP?

Comment: Can you share the code of PHP and C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you terminating the write message in C#?  I had an issue like that before that was resolved by appending an "\r" to the streamwriter.

E.g.

```
byte[] outStream = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stuffToWrite + "\r");
```

Comment: Thank you your answer resolved indirectly my issue. The server expected a increasing timestamp as first part of the answer. However because the computer I send the message from has a pretty long uptime it caused a integer 32 overflow which lead to the server ignoring my request